# a question about char *s_gets(char *st, int n)

Tags: c, fgets

I read a snippet of code from C Primer Plus, and tried hard to understand
  `char *s_gets(char *st, int n)`.
I don't the meaning of `if(ret_val)`. I think it can be deleted. Because `ret_val` is not `NULL`,I think `if(ret_val)` is equivalent to `if(1)`.

```
char *s_gets(char *st, int n)
{
char *ret_val;
char * find;

ret_val = fgets(st,n,stdin);

if(ret_val)
{
    find = strchr(st,'\n');
    if(find)
    {
        *find = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        while(getchar() != '\n')
        continue;
    }
}
return ret_val;}
```

It is my second time to edit.

Now, my understanding is as followed:

At first, `char *s_gets(char *st, int n)` has the similar function to `fgets(char *st,n,stdin)`. But the difference is that `*s_gets` will not read `'\n'`.

We presume `char *st` is "Practice makes perfect!".The length about `st` is 26.

The first situation, if `0< n < 26`, and then `if(ret_val)` is equivalent to `if(1)`.

The second situation, if `n == 26`, `if(find)` will be implemented.

The last situation, if `n == 0` or `n > 26`, `ret_val` will be `NULL`, so if statement will not be implemented. Am I right?

Comment: "Because ret_val is not NULL". How do you know that that will always be the case? That's obviously not true and there are cases where it can be `NULL`.

Comment: @OP can you please read to us -from the manual- what the possible return values of `fgets` are?

Comment: `strchar` --> did you mean `strchr`?

Comment: @Cheatah.Now, my understanding is as followed:

At first, `char *s_gets(char *st, int n)` has the similar function to `fgets(char *st,n,stdin)`. But the difference is that `*s_gets` will not read `'\n'`,right? 
We presume `char *st` is `"Practice makes perfect!"`.The length about st is 26.The first situation, if `0< n < 26,` and then `if(ret_val)` is equivalent to `if(1)`. The second situation, if `n == 26`, `if(find)` will be implemented. The last situation, if `n = 0` or `n > 26`, `ret_val` will be `NULL`, so `if statement` will not be implemented. Am I right?

Comment: the function; `s_gets()` is not portable.  Suggest actually using: `fgets()` in  `while()` loop and the first statement inside the while() loop would be: `st[ strcspn( st, "\n" ) ] = '\0';` to eliminate any possible trailing newline.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding; `continue;` this will fail, because there is no enclosing `for()` or `while()` loop for the code to jump back to

Answer (score 3):

No, the check is there for a reason. As per the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for `fgets()`,

> *...`fgets()` return `s` on success, and `NULL` on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.*

So, we need to check if the `fgets()` call is success and valid input has been read into `st`, before processing the input.